# How to Disable Cell Formula Suggestions?

Tags: excel, vba

I am designing an ID scanner, and I do not want any kind of autocorrection or cell suggestions so the barcode can scan properly and cleanly.  I am trying to diable any such pop-up or drop-down.  Right now, I can't seem to find the appropriate call to disable the Formula suggestion dropdown.  I have attempted the following lines to disable all versions of autocorrecting:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
    Application.EnableAutoComplete = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Application.AutoCorrect.DisplayAutoCorrectOptions = False
End Sub
```

What else can I try?

This is what I'm talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. You can turn off Formula Autocompletion via Excel Options (under Formula) or in code

```
Application.DisplayFormulaAutoComplete=False
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thank You.

Comment: My pleasure. Looks like the only thing you didn't try!